# D3, update plotted data upon zoom/pan

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bunch of points plotted to a D3 topojson map with some json data and I am working on trying to get it to zoom in. I have a very simple zoom working, however the points I have plotted are not moving/updating with the zoom.

See here  - http://jsfiddle.net/o3dxgfuu/6/

Here is the basic set up :

```
 var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid")
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
.attr("width", m_width)
.attr("height", m_width * height / width);

 svg.append("rect")
.attr("class", "background")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)

  var g = svg.append("g");

 d3.json("scripts/world-110m2.json", function(error, us) {
  g.append("g")
.attr("id", "countries")
.selectAll("path")
.data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.countries).features)
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
.attr("d", path)

});
```

And then the points are plotted in a function so I may swap them as needed (this maybe part of the issue, I'm not too sure) -

```
 function plotPoints(data){
 svg.selectAll("circle")
 .transition()
 .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 2; })
 .attr("r", 0 )
 .remove()

svg.selectAll(".pin")
.data(data.earthquakes)
.enter().append("circle", ".pin")
.on('mouseover', tip.show)
.on('mouseout', tip.hide)
 .attr("transform", function(d) {
 return "translate(" + projection([
  d.lon,
  d.lat
 ]) + ")"

 })
.attr("r", 0 )
.transition()
.duration(500)
.delay(function(d, i) { return i * 5; })
.attr("r",function(d){
   return d.magnitude/2;
 })
```

I am using the zoom methods, I found some pretty good examples -

```
 var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
.on("zoom",function() {
    g.attr("transform","translate("+ 
        d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
    g.selectAll(".pin")
        .attr("d", path.projection(projection));

});

svg.call(zoom)
```

so, the zoom and pan work great, I am having trouble trying to get my plotted points to update when I zoom and pan, it looks like they are on a sheet of glass over the map right now and don't move when I move the map. Thanks!

Edit : I have made an example of this here -

http://jsfiddle.net/o3dxgfuu/6/

You see when you zoom in the plotted points do not move. Still stuck on this :(. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the whole code, perhaps in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @SteveBennett I've dropped the whole controller in a fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/bL4mmty6/  , I will work on getting a running copy, might take a bit

Comment: @SteveBennett Added - sorry that took so long!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/o3dxgfuu/12/

The changes that I've made are:

1. Added a new `g` element to hold the `circle.pin` elements:

   ```
   var g = svg.append("g");
   var gPins = svg.append("g"); //new g element
   ```
2. Added the `circle` elements to the new `g` element:

   ```
   // svg.selectAll(".pin")
   gPins.selectAll(".pin") // add circles to new g element
     .data(data.earthquakes)
   .enter().append("circle", ".pin")
     .attr("transform", function(d) {
       return "translate(" + projection([
         d.lon,
         d.lat
         ]) + ")"

       })
   ```
3. Transform the new `g` element in your zoom handler

   ```
   var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
       .on("zoom",function() {
           g.attr("transform","translate("+ 
             d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
           gPins.attr("transform","translate("+ 
            d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")"); // transform new g element

     });
   ```

Basically, you should be adding your `circle` elements to a group, and then applying the `transform` to the group element.